# Evitar redundancia entre llaves foraneas de 2 tablas que dependen una de la otra

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

¡Buenas!

Estoy diseñando una base de datos de una tienda, tengo un problema que quiero evitar. Tengo las siguientes tablas (no están completas, son solo para explicar mi problema.).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Bien, el problema que quiero evitar es que cuando haga un insert a la tabla venta, no quiero agregar un null o algún valor que posteriormente tenga que actualizar para cuando, posterior al insert de la tabla venta, haga un insert en la tabla TablaPagos.

¿Existe alguna manera, alguna buena práctica, para evitar ese tipo de redundancias o loops interdependientes? ¿O realmente no es tan malo? Esto es para hacer rutas en mi API mas limpias.

Gracias de antemano, sigo investigando y pensando al respecto.

**Update 1.**
Cambie la imagen de mis tablas. Me había equivocado. La única relación de TablaPagos con Venta es el fkVenta.

Comment: No terminan de entenderse tus entidades, ¿cuál es la intención de venta?, lo digo por que luego veo que en la de `TablaPagos` almacenas valores relativos a la venta, ¿podrías explicar mejor?

Comment: Cierto, me equivoque, ya cambie la imagen a como es la relación. Gracias por detectar eso.

Comment: Y, si la lógica de negocio cambia (por necesidad de acoplarse a circunstancias) y una venta admite varios pagos y varias modalidades de pago ¿rehaces el modelo de datos? Va una idea con el mínimo necesario, puedes agregar en cada punto lo que necesites: Divide y gobierna: **Ventas**: {idventa, lovendido, cuando} **Pagos**: {idpago, monto, cuando} **relacion_ventas_pagos**: { idrel, idpago, idventa } (idrel para que un eventual muchos a muchos sea posible sin necesidad de cambios en el modelo)

Comment: No entraré en discusion respecto al diseño de las tablas, porque no es esa tu pregunta. Desde el punto de vista de las bases de datos relacionales no encuentro una manera para insertar dos filas nuevas (una en cada tabla de tu diseño) y que estén relacionadas entre si, distinta a la que describes: 1) fkTablaPagos y acepte null 2) insertar la nueva fila en Venta 3) Insertar la nueva fila en TablaPagos con fkVenta igual al idVenta la fila insertada en Venta y luego actualizar la columna fkTablaPagos con el idTablaPagos de la fila insertada en TablaPagos.

Comment: @MauricioOrtega De hecho si es parte de mi pregunta, el como evitar este tipo de casos. Si el diseño esta mal y debería ser de otra manera me gustaría saberlo.

Comment: El inconveniente de responder una pregunta de diseño, orientada a un dominio de problema específico se sale del propósito de la plataforma, ya que la respuesta se va a basar en opiniones y requiere el conocer todo el dominio del modelo de negocio que esta implementando. Pienso que en su caso, por lo que intenta hacer es "Una Venta tiene varios pagos" y "Un pago Tiene Varias Ventas" es una relacion muchos a muchos que en un modelo relacional se implementa con una tabla intermedia que contiene la pareja de claves primarias de las tablas que se relacionan

Comment: Si es correcta mi suposicion, revise este enlace https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1eUn6lsZ7c4